# Spring autowiring for unit tests, overriding dependency with mock

Tags: java, spring, unit-testing, dependency-injection

I have a service with autowired dependency. The dependency is in the same package as the tested service class and I need to replace it during autowiring with a custom mocking class (not Mockito).

```
       @Service
       public class ServiceClass {
           @Autowired
           DependencyClassA dependencyA;

           @Autowired
           DependencyClassB dependencyBToMock;
           //...
        }

        public class ServiceClassTest {
           //Tests

           @Service
           public static class DependencyClassBMock {
              //...
           }
        }
```

One of the limitations is old Spring version 2.5.4 that cannot be upgraded.

It is possible to override autowiring to select mock instead of real implementation?

Comment: It all depends on how your Spring configuration for production and testing looks like.

Comment: I'm using component scanning to auto detect components.
I could use manual listing of components in test configuration XML, however I would prefer not to.

Comment: What is the problem you are facing? I see no problem in what you want to achieve, so maybe I misunderstood the question... Can you share more details - configuration of your test + better description how it works and what you expect it will work?

Comment: I want to keep the component scanning on, since some of my tests include several services autowired together and I would like to avoid listing them in XML, however I do need to mock one or two of them since they access external systems or database. In order to load mock I need somehow to override the real component binding and force Spring to inject my mock.
I hope this is more clear now.

Comment: Unit tests shouldn't rely on Spring for the injection. Just inject the independencies by yourself, or using Mockito annotations.